# How to replace array key by its value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array('Elnett', 'INOA INOA', 'Playball P', 'Preferred Color Specialist', 
      'Série Expert', 'Série Nature', 'Techni art')
```

I would like to have keys and values like:

```
array('Elnett' => 'Elnett', 
      'INOA INOA' => 'INOA INOA', 
      'Playball P' => 'Playball', 
      'Preferred Color Specialis' => 'Preferred Color Specialist', 
      'Série Expert' => 'Série Expert', 
      'Série Nature' => 'Série Nature', 
      'Techni art' => 'Techni art')
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. If you want to preserve whitespace (indentation and new lines) for text that isn't code (such as the sample arrays), use `<pre>` elements. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: Also, complete, concise [sample code](http://sscce.org/) is always more helpful than a dump.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $out[$value] = $value;
}

print_r($out);
```

Comment: Wrong answer. The first array (`$array`) was like this: `[0=>'Elnett', 1=>'INOA INOA', ...]`. After these transformations we get this array (`$out`): `[0=>'Elnett', 1=>'INOA INOA', 'Elnett'=>'Elnett', 'INOA INOA'=>'INOA INOA', ...]`.

Comment: did you even test this code?  what happens to the original keys? this will just duplicate your array

Comment: As the `$out` is a fresh array, the original keys are not in there.. you can see the tinker here: https://onlinephp.io/c/15b84

Answer (score 31):

There's [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create a key/value array out of two arrays. Should be possible to use the same array for keys and values:

```
$names = array_combine($names, $names);
```

Answer (score 10):

This one-line answer may be useful to someone.

```
$trans = array_flip($array);
```

https://www.php.net/array_flip

array_flip returns the value=>key format of given key=>value array.
as the question changed, this does not exactly answer the OP's  question anymore.

Comment: between this and the other answer here you can start with `$a = array( 'foo' => 'bar' )` and do (1) `array_combine($a, $a)` to get `array( 'bar' => 'bar' )`,  (2) `array_flip($a)` to get `array( 'bar' => 'foo' )`, (3) `array_combine( array_flip($a), array_flip($a) )` to get `array( 'foo' => 'foo' )`

Comment: Just watch out for `array_flip` when all of your keys are unique, but your values contain duplicates. You will end up with a smaller array than you started with, which may or may not have been your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this. Not sure if there is a cleaner way to do it.

```
foreach($names as $key => $name){
    $names[$name] = $name;
    unset($names[$key]);
}
```

Comment: What about this array: `array(0, 1, 2)` :)